# How to share current page to blogger just like facebook's like button?

Tags: javascript, blogger

I want to add a button in my website just like facebook's like button, which share my site to blogger, but I found on blogger's developer site, it seems that there is no similar javascript available ?

Please point me the right direction, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Add This](http://www.addthis.com/)

This has almost all options to share and they have API too..

Comment: but i am afraid that they might not support it later on